# Java simpe Mysql query

Tags: java, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple Mysql SELECT query

Here is my code :

```
public Highscore[] load_localscores() {
        // load preferences
        SharedPreferences hiscores = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(screen.getApplicationContext());
        Highscore highscore[] = new Highscore[highscore_number];

        for (int i = 0; i < highscore_number; i++) {
            highscore[i] = new Highscore();
            highscore[i].highscore = HERE_SELECTED_MYSQL_DATA;
            highscore[i].hiscorename = HERE_SELECTED_MYSQL_DATA;
        }
return highscore;
```

In Mysql database i have two fields Hightscore.name and Hightscore.score

I want to select data from my table to HERE_SELECTED_MYSQL_DATA

i apologize i'm not so familiar with JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) to access the database. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm)'s a good example to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
        String selectSQL = "select * from Hightscore";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);

        System.out.println(rs1.getString("name"));
        System.out.println(rs1.getString("score"));
    }
        catch(SQLException se) {
        System.err.println(se);
    }
```

Hope this helps, it will get the result set but you have to make the connection beforehand. If you want advice about this I can give that too?